# Saxon EE 11.2 TransformToString() produces JET RUNTIME with an exit code of 9

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, saxon

So Ive been using "XsltExecutable::TransformtoString()" , it works with most of my xslts , but i have an xslt that produces a JET RUNTIME ERROR and returns with an exit code of 9.

I've searched what "exit code 9" means , and it said that it means that the OS is killing the program because I dont have enough memory ?????

This works with "TransformFiletoFile()" and all my other xslts but not this one.

This Xslt is using "xsl:result document" to output multiple files. Ive tried setting "BaseOutputURI()" but it still doesn't work . here is some more info :

Xml size :
`192,957  KB`

Xslt size (The One That Fails) : `24  KB`

Code :

```
SaxonProcessor* processor = new SaxonProcessor(false);
Xslt30Processor* xslt = processor->newXslt30Processor();

XdmNode* xmlfile = processor->parseXmlFromFile( Xml File );
XsltExecutable* xslte = xslt->compileFromFile( Xslt File );

std::string File = xslte->transformToString();   // Fails here
```

Output :
[image]

Example xml file :

```
<xml>
 <value>5</value>
</xml>
```

Example xslt file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message>producing sheet</xsl:message>
    <xsl:result-document href="output.xml">
      <result>
        <value>You put a <xsl:value-of select="/xml/value"/></value>
      </result>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As originally looked like you wanted to create output files anyway and just ended up using `transformToString` due to the bug with `transformToFile`, does the workaround by O'Neil (Saxonica's @ond1) to use `applyTemplatesReturningFile` perhaps work more reliably than using `transformToString`, particularmente with transformations creating large results where stuffing every result in a string might indeed run into memory problems?

Comment: As for `xsl:result-document` not working, is that not working at all for you so far or is it just not working with that particular scenario where you get the exit code 9 from the JET runtime? In any case, I would do it step by step, first try to run your code through the `Transform.exe`, perhaps with `-t` as it then outputs which result files it created, then try to use the same XSLT and XML with the API.

Comment: Transform.exe works with my xslt file

Comment: ApplyTemplateReturningFile doesnt work with any of my xslts ,

Comment: That astonishes me, I have just done a test using `applyTemplatesReturningFile` with an XSLT document splitting up a sequence of `item` elements into separate result files, one for each item, without problems. Perhaps let's look into one of your attempt with all details as a separate question/issue.

Comment: Additionally, I think O'Neil said he has a unit test on `applyTemplatesReturningFile`, so that code path should have some test coverage.

Comment: Hi, is it possible you can send me your stylesheet and XML files  or versions of the files that reproduces the crash please? Also I always find it useful after the compiling stage of the stylesheet to check if there are any errors:

if (xslte->exceptionOccurred()) {
            cout << xslte->getErrorMessage() << endl;
        }

Comment: I've updated the question to have sample xml and xslt files

Comment: Also do you know when the maintenence release is coming out , it would be good to go back to saxon HE

Comment: I have posted some code sample as an "answer", mainly because a C++ code snippet doesn't fit in any way into a comment. Check whether that helps clarifying why your attempts with `applyTemplatesReturningFile` failed.

Comment: hmm okay ill check that out , but can you answer the question please

Comment: The first SaxonC 11 release was done at the beginning of February this year and since then they already produced two maintenance releases, so if that continues I would expect 11.3 in a few weeks. But I don't know what plans Saxonica has.

Comment: Ok can you test it with my sample files

Comment: Maintenance release should be out in the next 1-2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I can run the sample XSLT against the sample XML fine, creating `output.xml` fine (and an empty `applyTemplatesReturnFileTest3.xml` as the main template does not output anything) with `applyTemplatesReturningFile` e.g. sample C++ code is

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "../../Saxon.C.API/SaxonProcessor.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmValue.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmItem.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmNode.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmFunctionItem.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/DocumentBuilder.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmMap.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmArray.h"
//#include "cppExtensionFunction.h"
#include "CppTestUtils.h"
#include <string>
//#include <thread>




using namespace std;


#ifdef MEM_DEBUG
#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#endif





/*
* Test applyTemplatesReturningFile. Source and stylesheet and output supplied as arguments
*/
void testApplyTemplatesReturningFile(SaxonProcessor* processor, Xslt30Processor* trans, sResultCount* sresult) {

    cout << "Test: transformToFile:" << endl;

    const char* xsltFile = "result-document-test2.xsl";
    const char* inputFile = "source2.xml";
    const char* resultFile = "applyTemplatesReturningFileTest3.xml";

    remove(resultFile);

    XdmNode* xmlfile = processor->parseXmlFromFile(inputFile);
    XsltExecutable* xslte = trans->compileFromFile(xsltFile);

    xslte->setGlobalContextItem(xmlfile);

    xslte->setInitialMatchSelection(xmlfile);

    xslte->applyTemplatesReturningFile(resultFile);


    if (CppTestUtils::exists(resultFile)) {
        cout << "The file " << resultFile << " exists" << endl;
        //remove(resultFile);
        sresult->success++;
    }

    else {
        cout << "The file " << resultFile << " does not exist" << endl;
        if (xslte->exceptionOccurred()) {
            cout << xslte->getErrorMessage() << endl;
        }
        sresult->failure++;
        sresult->failureList.push_back("testApplyTemplatesReturningFile");
    }

}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    const char* cwd = nullptr;
    if (argc > 0) {
        cwd = argv[1];
    }

    SaxonProcessor* processor = new SaxonProcessor(true);

    cout << "Test: Xslt30Processor with Saxon version=" << processor->version() << endl << endl;

    char buff[FILENAME_MAX]; //create string buffer to hold path
    GetCurrentDir(buff, FILENAME_MAX);
    cout << "CWD = " << buff << endl;
    if (cwd != nullptr) {
        processor->setcwd(cwd);
    }
    else {
        processor->setcwd(buff);
    }
    if (processor->isSchemaAwareProcessor()) {

        std::cerr << "Processor is Schema Aware" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Processor is not Schema Aware" << std::endl;
    }

    sResultCount* sresult = new sResultCount();

    Xslt30Processor* trans = processor->newXslt30Processor();

    if (trans == nullptr) {
        cout << "Error creating Xslt30Processor" << endl;
        if (processor->exceptionOccurred()) {
            cout << "Error message: " << processor->getErrorMessage() << endl;

        }
        return -1;
    }
 

    testApplyTemplatesReturningFile(processor, trans, sresult);

    cout << endl << "=============================================================" << endl << endl;


    fflush(stdout);



    delete trans;
    delete processor;
    processor->release();


    cout << endl << "======================== Test Results ========================" << endl << endl;

    std::cout << "\nTest Results - Number of tests= " << (sresult->success + sresult->failure) << ", Successes = "
        << sresult->success << ",  Failures= " << sresult->failure << std::endl;

    std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
    std::cout << "Failed tests:" << std::endl;
    // Make iterate point to beginning and increment it one by one until it reaches the end of list.
    for (it = sresult->failureList.begin(); it != sresult->failureList.end(); it++) {
        //Print the contents
        std::cout << it->c_str() << std::endl;

    }

    delete sresult;

#ifdef MEM_DEBUG
    SaxonProcessor::getInfo();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that you've used "SetGlobalContextItem()" , I didn't use that before

Comment: It should only be necessary if the stylesheet does any global variable or parameter initialization based on the primary input e.g. `<xsl:param name="foo-elements" select="//foo"/>`.

Comment: I've created a bug for this on my Saxonica Account

Comment: Fine, that way you get a faster reaction from O'Neil, I think.

Answer (score 0):

For the code

```
SaxonProcessor* processor = new SaxonProcessor(false);
Xslt30Processor* xslt = processor->newXslt30Processor();

XdmNode* xmlfile = processor->parseXmlFromFile( Xml File );
XsltExecutable* xslte = xslt->compileFromFile( Xslt File );

std::string File = xslte->transformToString();
```

you have show, I don't see any use of `xmlfile`, I think you want `xslte->transformToString(xmlfile)`.

But there might indeed be a problem with `transformToString` and `xsl:result-document`, I run into

```
Error in xsl:result-document/@href on line 6 column 42 of result-document-test2.xsl:
  SXRD0002  The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown
  In template rule with match="/" on line 4 of result-document-test2.xsl
     invoked by xsl:result-document at file:///C:/Program%20Files/Saxonica/SaxonC%20EE%2011.2/samples/cppTests/result-document-test2.xsl#6
```

although at least setcwd on the processor was done. Will need to check more details.

You can check for any errors during XSLT execution in your C++ code with e.g.

```
   const char* result = xslte->transformToString(NULL);
   if (!xslte->exceptionOccurred()) {
        cout << "The result " << result << " was created." << endl;
        sresult->success++;
    }
    else {
        cout << "An error occured." << endl;
        cout << xslte->getErrorMessage() << endl;
    }
```

I think, to avoid the base output URI problem, if you load the XSLT from a file and you want the main result as a string (e.g. with `transformToString`) while providing relative URIs/file names for secondary result documents, in the XSLT you can use e.g. `<xsl:result-document href="{resolve-uri('output.xml', static-base-uri())}">` to do that. In that case you don't have to set the base output URI from the C++ API.

Comment: I tried to use xml file with transformtoString() , but it still didnt work

Comment: when i set the cwd on the processor to where the xslts are , it fails for everything single xslt and xml , it displays exit code 9

Comment: Can You Bring O Neil here ??

Comment: Let him deal with your bug issue on the Saxonica site, don't expect him to deal with the same issue raised on two different channels.

Comment: The error  "SXRD0002  The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown" can be solved with:  xslte->setBaseOutputURI("file:///location/");

Comment: BTW as Martin pointed out you can pass the source document using: transformToString(XdmNode *source)

Comment: See bug issue for further details: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5376

Comment: what exactly is baseOutputURI() , do you pass in a char *  that contains a filename , or it contains a directory name ???

Comment: Also using "xsl:result-document" , it outputs the xml files into the same directory as the xslt file that used "result-document" , how to I tell it where to output the files .

Comment: A file URI as the base output URI on Windows would have the form of e.g. `file:///C:/Dir/Subdir/` or `file:/home/user1/folder1/subfolder2/` on Linux I think, if you want to capture the main result as a string but push out `xsl:result-document`s with relative URIs/file names to that directory. I don't know whether C++ has some convenience methods in the standard library to go from an OS specific file path to a file URI.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show that from within XSLT with e.g. `<xsl:result-document href="{resolve-uri('output.xml', static-base-uri())}">` you can ensure that relative result URIs for `xsl:result-document` are resolved against the stylesheet's URI, even when the primary result is a string, as with `transformToString`. That way you don't need the C++ API.